# How do I sort two glossaries differently? list of acronyms(sort=standard) and list of symbols(sort=use)

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms, sorting

I'm using the `glossaries` package to create a list of acronyms and a list of symbols.

I have to do a list of acronyms sorted alphabetically (`sort=standard`) and a list of symbols ordered by appearance (`sort=use`). Both lists have to be displayed before the ToC. I read the user manual for `glossaries.sty v4.02` where there is a similar example in which acronyms are ordered alphabetically and notations are sorted in the order in which they were defined but I could not adapt it to my needs.

Is it possible to do this? Because according with some readings, I have to define the entries before print the glossaries, which means, before I use them in the text.

For now, I'm cheating and forcing the correct order by putting `sort={001}, sort={002}, ...,sort={XXX}` at the glossary entries and setting the `glossaries` option `sort=standard` so both acronyms and the main glossary are being ordered alphabetically.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside,a4paper,english,french,spanish,brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage[subentrycounter,seeautonumberlist,acronym,style=long3colheaderborder]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{pi}{
            name={\ensuremath{\pi}},
            description={ratio of circumference of circle to its diameter},
            sort={003} }
\newglossaryentry{real number}{
            name={\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}},
            description={include both rational numbers and irrational numbers,
                a real number can be given by an infinite decimal
                representation, the real numbers may be thought of as points on an infinitely
                long number line},
            sort={002} }
\newglossaryentry{sigma}{
            name={\ensuremath{\sigma}},
            description={greek symbol},
            sort={001} }
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{\textit{#1} \glsseelist{#2}}
```

Answer (score 5):

The different sort mechanisms aren't compatible with each other. In particular, since `sort=use` doesn't set the `sort` key until the entry is actually used in the document, you can't use the method given in the [sampleSort.tex](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/sampleSort.tex) example file. It is however possible to modify the underlying sort macros for this particular case, but it involves using internals, which I'd prefer to avoid:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\makeglossaries

% First define entries with sort=standard:

\newacronym{zfc}{ZFC}{Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory}

\newacronym{ad}{AD}{axiom of determinacy}

\newacronym{nf}{NF}{new foundations}

% Modify the sort macro to use sort=def just for "main" glossary
\makeatletter
\setupglossaries{sort=use}

\@gls@defsortcount{main}
\let\orgsetsort\@gls@setsort

\renewcommand{\@gls@setsort}[1]{%
  \ifdefstring{\gls@type}{main}{\orgsetsort{#1}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{pi}%
{
   name={\ensuremath{\pi}},
   description={ratio of circumference of circle to its diameter}%
}

\newglossaryentry{real number}%
{
   name={\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}},
   description={include both rational numbers and
     irrational numbers, a real number can be given 
     by an infinite decimal representation, the real 
     numbers may be thought of as points on an infinitely
     long number line}%
}

\newglossaryentry{sigma}%
{
  name={\ensuremath{\sigma}},
  description={greek symbol}%
}

\begin{document}

Reference the acronyms: \gls{zfc}, \gls{ad}, \gls{nf}.

Reference the symbols: \gls{sigma}, \gls{real number}, \gls{pi}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]